# How to transform/migrate a mysql trigger to a Sql Server Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I did a trigger in mysql to shoot alerts always an input value was less than the set value. But now I need it is done in SQL SERVER.

I would be grateful if someone could help me transform mysql trigger to a SQL Server trigger.

Thanks to all at once.

---

My trigger is:

```
DELIMITER $$
create TRIGGER alert
AFTER INSERT ON records
FOR EACH ROW
begin
Set @comp=0;
Set @tempmax=0;
Set @tempmin=0;

select lim_inf_temp into @tempmin from sensores where idSensor=NEW.idSensor;


Set @maxidAlarme=0;
if (CAST(NEW.Temperatura AS UNSIGNED)<@tempmin) then
SELECT MAX(idAlarme) into @maxidAlarme FROM alarmes;
SET @maxidAlarme=@maxidAlarme+1;
INSERT INTO alarmes(idAlarme,descricao_alarme, idRegisto) VALUES (@maxidAlarme,"inserted below the normal temperature",New.idRegisto);
INSERT INTO sensores_tem_alarmes(idSensor,idAlarme,dataAlarme) VALUES (NEW.idSensor,@maxidAlarme,NOW());
set @comp=+1;
end if; 


set @id_sensores_em_alerta=1;
SELECT MAX(id_sensores_em_alerta) into @id_sensores_em_alerta FROM sensores_em_alerta;
 INSERT INTO sensores_em_alerta(id_sensores_em_alerta, idSensor, idAlarme, data_registo, numerosensoresdisparados) VALUES (id_sensores_em_alerta,NEW.idSensor, @maxidAlarme, NOW(), @comp);
end $$;

DELIMITER  ;
```

---

I've tried to make the trigger in SQL Server, but as the script is different and I'm getting many difficulties to do the right way.

My attempt that was not going at all well:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Alert ON registos AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @comp decimal= 0
DECLARE @tempmax decimal= 0
DECLARE @tempmin decimal= 0


DECLARE @current_max_idAlarme int = (SELECT MAX(IdAlarme) FROM alarmes)

-- Insert into alarmes from the inserted rows if temperature less than tempmin
INSERT alarmes (IdAlarme, descricao_alarme, idRegisto)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.idRegisto) + @current_max_idAlarme,
    'temp Error',
    i.idRegisto
FROM
    inserted AS i
WHERE
    i.Temperatura < @tempmin

END
```

But dont do anything.
Dont create data on table alarmes :S

Does anyone could help me please. I would be eternally grateful.

Many Greetings and thank you all.

Comment: make all your declare statement with datatype; declare @comp int(2) = 0

Comment: Thanks for reply. And the other errors :S  I really don't know how solve this problem.

Comment: Is the `NEW` the same as the `inserted` table in MSSQL?

Comment: Note that MySQL uses (only) row-level triggers whereas SQL Server (only) has statement level triggers. The way of dealing with the "inserted" data is completely different with these two approaches

Comment: Thank's for reply. It's my firt time in sql server, and i'm getting very dificult to do the same trigger but in sql server...

Comment: Gah! there are a few things that are going to hurt you here. - For one it looks like you are implicitly inserted into a surrogate autonumbered key? alarmes.idAlarme is not automatic?

Comment: You'd usually do a select on the virtual INSERTED table (that holds all the rows that was just inserted) using a WHERE clause to filter the rows you were interested in. However, you'll need to probably cursor over that and then do an insert into your alarmes table (because of the lack of an IDENTITY surrogate key on (IdAlarme) -- I was writing something until I noticed that and then I stopped. The real problem you have is probably not the trigger - its your table design stopping you from doing something simple and set based.

Comment: Thanks for reply @TransactCharlie. alarmes.idAlarm is not automatic. That trigger create an idAlarme.

Comment: What i'm suposed to do?

Comment: can you redesign any of the tables?

Comment: It is not very easy. Because I'm collecting data from a parser. There's just no way to convert this trigger? I can make the id's automatic.It Helps?

Comment: I'm going to post a framework of a trigger - I think you should add a IDENTITY key to the tables because that way its: a) easier and b) safer - what happens if two processes insert and triggers fire at the same time. At the moment you will get key conflicts. My answer will be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, MSSQL doesn't have the option `FOR EACH ROW`, so it treats multiple inserted rows at once as a set. You will therefore have to insert the values into a table variable.

Unfortunately I do not know much MySQL actually, but I believe this is a starting point?

```
CREATE TRIGGER ALERT
ON records
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @comp INT;
 DECLARE @tempmax INT;
 DECLARE TABLE @tempmin (tempmin INT);

 INSERT INTO @tempmin
 SELECT s.lim_inf_temp FROM sensores s WHERE s.idSensor IN (inserted.idSensor);
--rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Bit give me an error in "...WHERE idSensor=inserted.idSensor;" :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post this code against my better judgement - redesign the tables is better than this hack.

This uses a ROW_number() to virtualise a surrogate identity key for the alarmes table. This is a 'bad plan' (tm).

Also the answer is partial - it doesn't do everything your question asked for -- I hope it gets your further along the road. Use it as a guide for how to interact with the virtual INSERTED table. Good luck

```
CREATE TRIGGER Alert ON records AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @comp INT = 0
DECLARE @tempmax INT = 0
DECLARE @tempmin INT = 0

-- get the max current id.
-- note that this is EXTREMELY unsafe as if two pieces of code are executing
-- at the same time then you *will* end up with key conflicts.
-- you could use SERIALIZABLE.... but better would be to redisn the schema
DECLARE @current_max_idAlarme = (SELECT MAX(IdAlarme) FROM alarmes)

-- Insert into alarmes from the inserted rows if temperature less than tempmin
INSERT alarmes (IdAlarme, descricao_alarme, idRegisto)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.idRegisto) + @current_max_idAlarme,
    'temp Error',
    i.idRegisto
FROM
    inserted AS i
WHERE
    i.Temperatura < @tempmin

END
```

Comment: also I wrote it in notepad, so syntax might well be wrong - I haven't had to write tsql in a looooong time!

Comment: sorry - too used to python

Comment: string literals are single quotes in tsql - d'oh - ammended my answer -- I hope you aren't running this on production? You're not running it on production right? right? Cause -- that would be..... a bad thing

Comment: Thank you again. I had already noticed this detail. 
There is a small problem. When testing inserts to shoot the trigger dont do anything: S you know why?

Comment: I'd guess the rows you are inserting into records don't have temperature less than 0? which is the only thing the triggers is checking for...

Comment: you could replace the code inside the trigger to just insert everything from INSERTED into a scrub table? using the tempdb is a good way to do that. Create a table in tempdb with the right schema and then just insert into that. You'll be able to watch the data flow from the trigger. Your only other real option is sql server profiler - which is awesome but rather difficult to use.

Comment: Thanks again for reply. You really help me to understand SQL Server. That trigger is checking for records that have temperatura less than 0. But I need this check is made to a field in another table. How can I do this?This is possible? Can you help me please?

Comment: Could you help me please  @Transact Charlie ?

Comment: No - I don't think so. I don't have the time. I've shown you the form of the trigger and the INSERTED virtual table you are after. I'd suggest making some test cases in simple tables (use tempdb to play with) -- and if you are getting nowhere - I'd ask for help on dbformus or sqlteam. Also have you even looked at the documentation. Sqlserver has really, really good documentation. I'm assuming sql server 2008 - this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189799.aspx